# Junit Test using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: spring, junit

I am trying to create junit test case using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.controller",
        "com.service",
        "com.repository" })
class CustomConfiguration {

}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration(classes = CustomConfiguration.class)
public class Test {

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private EmployeeController employeeController;

    @Mock
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmailId("admin@gmail.com");
        employee.setFirstName("admin");
        employee.setLastName("admin");

        Employee employee = employeeController.createEmployee(employee);
        assertNotNull(employee);
    }

}
```

It is giving error of No qualifying bean of type  EmployeeRepository.

Comment: Do you mean no bean of type `EmployeeService`? Where are you calling `EmployeeRepository`?

Comment: I have conntroller.From that I am calling Service and  from service I am calling repository. My problem is how can I apply all the required dependency in Test Case?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even tough you are having a custom configuration class for your test, the repository beans are not getting created in background through classpath scanning. If you are aiming for an integration test case rather than a junit one since you doesn't seem to mock anything in the code that you provided , why don't you try using more updated annotation version like using SpringRunner.class instead of SpringJunit4Runner.class , if your spring version supports it. If you are just aiming to create a unit test case. Create a mock bean for whatever you want to mock like :

```
@Mock
SomeRepository repo;
```

This mock should be automatically injected to your service beans when it starts up by junit.
If you are on springboot then:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Test { 
  
    @Mock
    EmployeeService employeeService;
 
    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeController employeeController;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmailId("admin@gmail.com");
        employee.setFirstName("admin");
        employee.setLastName("admin");

        when(employeeService.save(any)).thenReturn(employee);
        Employee employee = employeeController.createEmployee(employee);
        assertNotNull(employee);
    }

}
```

The above is a typical example for unit test in springboot , but in your case for controller classes springboot provides the annotation `@WebMvcTest` or unit testing the web layer only.If you want to do it like that , read [doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).

Comment: I did same as your instruction. Still not working. I am trying to create junit,Can you help me to achieve?

Comment: @Sanjay Which version of spring are you using  ? Please share the  entire stacktrace.

Comment: Spring boot - 2.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: https://github.com/SanjayBandhniya/junit-demo Attach code here.

Comment: Given scenario I have generated base on other project test case where controller is not there.I have a class where some dependency I have injected.that dependency is not resolving.it is giving same error that I have in given code.